# Custom DozerConverter is called only in SpringBoot test

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

The problem I am facing is that I have a Spring Boot application with a custom `DozerConverter` that gets called by a `DozerBeanMapper` only in a `@SpringBootTest` class, and not in a service class.

### How I define the DozerBeanMapper

The DozerBeanMapper is defined in a configuration class like so:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Mapper getMapper() {

        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        mapper.setMappingFiles(Collections.singletonList("mappings.xml"));

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

This is `mappings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

    <configuration>
        <custom-converters>
            <converter type="com.app.util.converter.EntityToDtoDozerConverter">
                <class-a>com.app.model.entity.Entity</class-a>
                <class-b>com.app.model.dto.Dto</class-b>
            </converter>
        <custom-converters>
    </configuration>

</mappings>
```

And this is the custom `DozerConverter`:

```
@Component
public class EntityToDtoDozerConverter extends DozerConverter<Entity, Dto> {

    private AnotherService myService;

    public EntityToDtoDozerConverter() {
        super(Entity.class, Dto.class);
    }

    public EntityToDtoDozerConverter(AnotherService myService) {
        this();
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public Dto convertTo(Entity entity, Dto dto) {

        if (dto == null)
            dto = new Dto();

        dto.setId(entity.getId());
        dto.setSubEntity(myService.findById(entity.getSubEntityId()));

        return dto;
    }

    @Override
    public Entity convertFrom(Dto dto, Entity entity) {

        if (entity == null)
            entity = new Entity();

        entity.setId(dto.getId());
        entity.setSubEntityId(dto.getSubEntity().getId());

        return entity;
    }
}
```

### Test class (where it works)

Here `mapper.map()` calls the custom converter as I would expect.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class DozerTests {

    @Autowired
    Mapper mapper;

    @Test
    void myTest() {

        Entity entity = new Entity(1, 2);

        Dto dto = mapper.map(entity, Dto.class);    // -----> Here the dto is correct

        ...
    }
}
```

### Service class (where it does not work)

Here `mapper.map()` does not call my custom converter, so SubEntity results in null value.

```
@Service
public class Service implements IService {

    private final Mapper mapper;
    private final EntityManager em;
    ...

    public Service(Mapper mapper, EntityManager em) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public Dto findById(int id) {

        Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("not found"));

        Dto dto = mapper.map(entity, Dto.class);    // ------> Here the dto is incorrect (null value for SubEntity)

        return dto;
    }


}
```

**Update:** debugging each case more deeply, I found out that what's causing the different behavior is the internal caching mechanism of Dozer. Specifically, when trying to map in the "service class" case, I can see that the mapper has internally some cached mappings that prevent him to load the custom converter. This is not the case when mapping in the test class.

Comment: just an idea... try `@Bean @Primary public Mapper getMapper() {...}`

Comment: same result, mapping in the test class works but not in the service class

Comment: another try: inject specific impl per Qualifier `@Bean @Qualifier("abc") public Mapper getMapper() {...}` and  `public Service(@Qualifier("abc")Mapper mapper...) `

Comment: still no difference :(

Comment: in which folder is mapping.xml file?

Comment: it's in `src/main/resources/`

Comment: Working for me with qualifier

Answer (score 1):

looks like an old unresolved bug... [Injected Custom Converters are not used](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/110)

Adding the custom converter to mapping.xml seems to use a (default) constructed instance  [Custom converter with Spring dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695884/custom-converter-with-spring-dependency-injection)

But then you should see an error because of missing `AnotherService` in your converter.

But no idea why it works in your test class.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your service doesn't find the `subEntity` :`dto.setSubEntity(myService.findById(entity.getSubEntityId()));`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this can't be the reason because the method `convertTo()` is never called in the service class case

Comment: if `convertTo` is not being invoked, then who converts `entity` to `dto`  from here `Dto dto = mapper.map(entity, Dto.class);` ?

Comment: the default dozer converter which is `PrimitiveOrWrapperConverter.java`

Comment: so , your `EntityToDtoDozerConverter` is not invoked ?

Comment: exactly! sorry if my description was not so clear